# Se insertan los datos duplicados

Tags: c#, entity-framework, controller, insert

Tengo un problema ya que el controlador me inserta los datos dobles (entra dos veces al controller) no entiendo el porque, aquí pondré el código del controlador.

El controller primero revisa que se haya clickeado el botón que se llama "no" y tiene valor 0 para llamar un procedimiento almacenado de `p_cm_BuscarSolicitud()` que devuelve una solicitud y esa solicitud luego la inserto en la tabla Proyectos (BI_Proyectos).

Ademas de eso cambio el estado de la solicitud con otro procedimiento almacenado, `p_cm_UpdateEstadoGerente()`, guardo los cambios y devuelvo un mensaje de proyecto creado con Json.

El problema aquí es que cuando hace eso vuelve y entra al controller e ingresa nuevamente todos los datos, creándome dos proyectos con la misma información de la solicitud que consulte.

```
            if (form["no"] == "0")
            {
                var solicitud = Convert.ToInt32(form["id"]);
                var user = form["user"];
       
                var proyecto = DB.p_cm_BuscarSolicitud(solicitud);

                BI_Proyecto proy = new BI_Proyecto();

                foreach (var i in proyecto)
                {
                    proy.id_solicitud = solicitud;
                    proy.nombre = i.nombre;
                    proy.id_departamento = i.id_departamento;
                    proy.responsable = user;
                    proy.id_estado = 6;
                    proy.id_etapa = i.id_etapa;
                    proy.fecha_solicitud = i.fecha_solicitud;
                    proy.fecha_inicio = System.DateTime.Now;
                    proy.usuario = i.id_proponente;
                    proy.coste = i.coste;
                    proy.introduccion = i.introduccion;
                    proy.descripcion = i.descripcion;
                    proy.propuesta = i.propuesta;
                    proy.id_mesa = i.id_mesa;
                    proy.fecha_final = System.DateTime.Now;                   
                }
                DB.p_cm_UpdateEstadoGerente(solicitud);

                DB.BI_Proyecto.Add(proy);
                DB.SaveChanges();

                var respuesta = "Su solicitud ahora es un proyecto";
                return Json(respuesta);
            }
            else
            {
                var solicitud = Convert.ToInt32(form["id"]);
                BI_Solicitud dp_solicitud = DB.BI_Solicitud.Find(solicitud);
                dp_solicitud.id_etapa = 5;
                DB.Entry(dp_solicitud).State = EntityState.Modified;
                DB.SaveChanges();

                var respuesta = "Su solicitud ha pasado a la siguiente fase";
                return Json(respuesta);
            }
```

El else funciona correctamente cuando quieres cambiar la solicitud a otra etapa, mi problema es cuando realiza el if y quiero crear el proyecto.

Comment: Hola Priscila.
Disculpa, has revisado, cuántos valores recibís de DB.p_cm_BuscarSolicitud(solicitud);?

Comment: Crea una variable de entorno (global) para registrar si el proyecto ha sido creado o no. Y, antes de crearlo verifica su valor, en caso de que ya haya sido creado saltas el bloque de instrucciones que lo crea, en otro caso lo creas y registras que está hecho en dicha variable. Si el método debe devolver valores ligados a crear el proyecto, puedes almacenarlos para recogerlos y devolverlos (de modo transparente) así te evitas rastrear la magia del Framework.

Comment: la solicitud trae 12 valores , sera eso el problema, porque no inserto esos 12 valores?

Comment: corregí el procedimiento almacenado para que trajera la misma cantidad de valores que inserto en la tabla proyectos, ahora trae exactamente 10 valores pero sigue insertando doble

Comment: Y la acción que crea el proyecto la ejecutas desde un botón tipo submit o una función de javascripts?

Comment: con un botón tipo submit desde un modal

Answer (score 0):

Al final resolví pero no creo que sea la manera correcta (pero la necesidad hizo que mi lógica inventara algo). Cree una validación que verifica si el id de la solicitud que inserto como un nuevo proyecto existe en la tabla BI_Proyectos, si no existe crea el proyecto,si ya existe entonces solo devuelve la vista. El problema con esta solución es que sigue entrando dos veces al controlador cosa que no debería suceder. En fin dejo mi corrección abajo por si alguien puede sugerir una idea mejor o optimizar esto con una solución mas eficiente.

```
 if (form["no"] == "0")
            {
                var solicitud = Convert.ToInt32(form["id"]);
                var user = form["user"];

                var proyecto = DB.p_cm_BuscarSolicitud(solicitud).FirstOrDefault();

                BI_Proyecto proy = new BI_Proyecto();

                var buscar = DB.BI_Proyecto.Where(x => x.id_solicitud == solicitud).ToList(); //busca la solicitud en la tabla

                if (buscar.Count == 0) { //verifico si mi lista viene sin ningun campo y procedo a insertar a la tabla BI_Proyecto
                proy.id_solicitud = solicitud;
                    proy.nombre = proyecto.nombre;
                    proy.id_departamento = proyecto.id_departamento;
                    proy.responsable = user;
                    proy.id_estado = 6;
                    proy.id_etapa = proyecto.id_etapa;
                    proy.fecha_solicitud = proyecto.fecha_solicitud;
                    proy.fecha_inicio = System.DateTime.Now;
                    proy.usuario = proyecto.id_proponente;
                    proy.coste = proyecto.coste;
                    proy.introduccion = proyecto.introduccion;
                    proy.descripcion = proyecto.descripcion;
                    proy.propuesta = proyecto.propuesta;
                    proy.id_mesa = proyecto.id_mesa;
                    proy.fecha_final = System.DateTime.Now;

                 DB.p_cm_UpdateEstadoGerente(solicitud);

                DB.BI_Proyecto.Add(proy);
                DB.SaveChanges();

                var respuesta = "Su solicitud ahora es un proyecto";
                return Json(respuesta);
                }

                else
                {
                    return View();
                }
```

Comment: Veo que haces cosas diferentes en la pregunta y respuesta, aqui en la respuesta, te fijas si existe, y en la pregunta recorrias esa lista para usar esos datos y llenarlos.

Comment: la validación la hago para que no me inserte doble los datos porque debo entregar el software hoy, pero sigue entrando dos veces al controlador y ese es el problema que quiero resolver pero por mientras encontré esta solución para que no se duplique los datos